# Why in the binomial expansion are the powers of x positive?

Tags: binomial-theorem

In Binomial expansion with $n$ as a rational, positive number then,

$$(x+y)^n =\binom{n}{0}y^n + \binom{n}{1}  y^{n-1}  x +\binom{n}{1}  y^{n-2}x^2 +\cdots+\binom{n}{n}  x^{n}$$

While if $\alpha$ is a rational, non-positive number and $\lvert x \rvert< 1$ then,

$$(1+x)^\alpha = 1 + \binom{\alpha}{1} x + \binom{\alpha}{2}  x^2 +\cdots$$
Imagine if $\alpha$ is $-3$ then how can $x$ be going up in positive powers?

Comment: The binomial expansion only works when $n$ is a non-negative integer. Also, the sum you write with ... at the end does not go on forever, but ends at $x^ny^0$. Also, the coefficients in the expansion are not fractions, they are binomial coefficients.

Comment: Consider $(1+x)^{-3}=\frac 1{(1+x)^3}=\frac 1{1+3 x+3 x^2+x^3}$ and use long division.

Comment: @MeesdeVries And then there is this : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton.27s_generalised_binomial_theorem

Comment: @macavity, you learn something new every day! My apologies.

Comment: @MeesdeVries no apologies needed - having a learning mindset is a blessing.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici: Wouldn't it be division by increasing power order instead?

Comment: @Bernard. Yes, for sure !

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to see this - from the theory of GP, it may be familiar to write for a common ratio $|x| < 1$,
$$\frac1{1-x} = 1+x+x^2+x^3 + \cdots$$

Using $x \to -x$, we get 
$$\frac1{1+x} = 1-x+x^2-x^3 + \cdots$$

If you differentiate that, you get
$$-\frac1{(1+x)^2} = -1+2x-3x^2+4x^3 -\cdots$$
$$\implies \frac1{(1+x)^2} = 1-2x+3x^2-4x^3 +\cdots$$

I hope you can extend easily to the case $\alpha = -3$...